# Back end и Front end

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, frontend, backend

Для чего нужны front-end библиотеки(React,Angular,Vue), если можно рисовать html в том же JSP.Я явно чего-то не понимаю. Накидайте пожалуйста ссылки на объяснение взаимосвязи Front-end и back-end.Даже если писать на Java EE, то как например туда React включить?

Answer (score 3):

FrontEnd нужен для выполнения кода на стороне клиента, т.е. в браузере.

Это даёт возможность создавать динамический контент (например индикаторы прогресса загрузки, анимации).

Сделать это на стороне сервера не выйдет. Если, конечно, не отсылать с сервера Html вместе с JavaScript, но и в этом случае последний будет исполняться на клиентском браузере.

А т.к. FronEnd пишут на JS, а бэкенд не всегда на нём и вообще там другая логика, то имеет смысл разделить кодовые базы и оставить логику (бизнес-логику, хранение данных etc) на BackEnd, а отображение пользовательского интерфейса делать отдельно, на JS. А на нём удобно использовать фреймворки. Отсюда и взялись все эти Angular, Vue, React etc.

При этом, если общение FronEnd и BackEnd устроить разумно, в виде http запросов с первого на API последнего, то потом можно аналогично просто добавлять другие клиенты, например мобильные приложения.

---

Если же программа простая и требуется только отобразить статичный список данных без всяких красивостей, то можно и просто HTML с бэка отдаавать. Но вот расширяемым (в сторону красивости и обилия типов клиентов) такое решение не будет.